# SharePoint solution deployment running forever - SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2007

I'm using following scripts to install/uninstall a solution

**Uninstall.bat**

```
@echo off

echo *****************************************************
echo Un-Installing <solution>  - 
echo (C) <company>. All rights reserved.
echo *****************************************************

set stsadm="%programfiles%\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe"

echo Retracing solution.wsp
%stsadm% -o retractsolution -name solution.wsp -immediate -allContentURLs

%stsadm% -o execadmsvcjobs

echo Wait till the solution retraction is completed (check the central administration)
pause

echo Deleting solution from the solution store
%stsadm% -o deletesolution -name solution.wsp -override

%stsadm% -o execadmsvcjobs

echo - Restarting WSS Timer service
net stop "windows sharepoint services timer"
net start "windows sharepoint services timer"

echo Uninstallation completed successfully

echo.
pause
```

**Install.bat**

```
@echo off
set STSADM="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe"

echo *****************************************************
echo Installing <solution>  - 
echo (C) <company>. All rights reserved.
echo *****************************************************

echo Adding solution.wsp to the solution store
%STSADM% -o addsolution -filename solution.wsp

echo Deploying solution
%STSADM% -o deploysolution -name solution.wsp -force -immediate -allowGacDeployment -allContentURLs

%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs

echo Installation completed successfully

IISRESET

Restarting SharePoint Timer Service..

NET STOP SPTIMERV3
NET START SPTIMERV3

REM echo copying resources..
REM %STSADM% -o copyappbincontent

echo.
pause
```

But the install.bat is stuck at `execadmsvcjobs` after the deployment. When I checked the TaskManager the CPU usage spiked up to 100% and STSADM.EXE and OWSTIMER.EXE was consuming lot of memory. So the deployment is running forever.

Any ideas?

Comment: what was solution in your case

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646646/feature-event-handler-called-multiple-times-for-farm-level-feature-sharepoint-2/4647028#4647028 was the issue and the root cause for the server being very slow. I used a static variable in the feature event handler and prevented from being called multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a common issue and unlikely to be a problem with the actual WSP file you are deploying. Have a look at the [following resources](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+stuck+on+deploying).

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to go through the log bieng genrated in 12 hive log folder that will help you to find the cause of the problem.

this type of problem arises when any of the required resources for deployment is missing or down for maintenance. Like if you have multiple web servers in your farm and any one is down due to some issues and you have not detached it from your SharePoint farms it tries to find it and since it is not available job hangs. same case may happen when you are trying to deploy it in all web apps and either of the web app is not available.

to kill the job which is continuously running you can take help from following post 
http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2008/12/10/removing-a-dead-solution-deployment-from-moss-2007.aspx

Comment: I dont have a farm setup. I'm just running this on my test server. Will check the logs though.

Comment: post the log message here will try to help you in tht